# Create remote repository from local files that are already on a local repo

Tags: git, bash, deployment, ssh

I am aware of the clone function that could do this, but the thing it would clone what is in the repo, being everything that was pushed.

What we need is to modify some files in our repository template and create a new repo with these modified files, without having to commit these files (that are project-dependant) to our template, so it stays intact.

Is that even possible? Using "git add", "git commit" and then "git push" with an extra parameter that would be the remote repository?

Basically, I want the files, not the repo.

Comment: You could use `git remote add`, then push to that new remote.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, however if we modify files from the template, they would also be pushed on all the projects that derivate from it and it might break things.

Comment: What is the relationship between the new repository and the original one supposed to be? I.e. should changes to the original repository (on the shared files) be reflected in the the new one? Or is it just a one-off copy?

Comment: Just a one-off copy, no strings attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the main repository (main) and the repositories inheriting (child1, child2). What I would do to start would be to create a branch per child on the main repository:

```
main$ git checkout -b child1
... edit/commit for child1 ...
main$ git checkout master
main$ git checkout -b child2 
... edit/commit for child2 ...
```

Now, you can do:

```
main$ git push git@yourserver:repositories/child1.git child1:master
main$ git push git@yourserver:repositories/child2.git child2:master
```

This pushes branch child1 on the master of repository child1. This way you can keep your main master clean. If this is a one off push, you can remove the branches afterwards. You main need to force the merge on the child repositories if you cannot fast forward ([see the refspec for the push](http://gitmanual.org/git-push.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to use a local clone to which you can apply the changes before you push to a remote. You could do the following:

1. Make a copy of the template repository.

   `git clone --no-hardlinks templaterepo newrepo`
2. Filter out the files that you don't want to keep from the old repository.

   `cd newrepo`

   `git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f sensitive/file1.txt file2.txt" HEAD`
3. Make any other change as you usually do in Git.

   `git add ...`

   `git commit ...`
4. Add a remote.

   `git remote add origin git@...`
5. Push

   `git push origin master`

This will ensure that you preserve the history for all the files that you actually cared about, and wipe out the history for the ones you don't care about (and which potentially contain sensitive data).

After step 1. `newrepo` has essentially no relationship to `templaterepo` anymore, other than a shared history (the `--no-hardlinks` is assuming you're cloning from the same filesystem and is just for extra speed), so whatever you do on your `templaterepo` afterwards, it won't affect the contents of `newrepo` (or its remote).

See `git help filter-branch` for more.